# Send Equation Symbol to an If Statement

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Basically, I have a function in VBA that you send some parameters to, and then it does some maths with it to give a value. One of the parameters I send is either a `"<"` or a `">"`, which are later used in an if statement of

```
if x > y
```

or

```
if x < y
```

depending on which I send.

At present, I send this as a string, labelled "constraint", and do the following;

```
if constraint = ">" then
  if x > y

    *code*
  end if

elseif constraint = "<" then
  if x < y
    *code*
  end if
end if
```

if that makes sense.

This gets complicated with the other code I have; is there a way I can neaten this up into one if statement?

Comment: If each operation was its own function you could pass the function around using `AddressOf` or use `Run`.

Comment: You could look at using `Application.Evaluate(x & constraint & y)` if you just need to get a True/False answer, or create a function to wrap up the code you posted.

Comment: Cheers for the responses. I'm working on making each operation its own function and doing it that way; it's the best way I could see. It slightly complicates things with my code later on though. What would be ideal is if I could just say "if x constraint y then..." and it puts in the < or >!

Comment: Actually, @Tim Williams, it seems that using application.evaluate is a solution. That should be fine then, Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

It appears that in both cases you need both the `constraint` to be a certain string AND the `x constraint y` to run code otherwise do nothing.  Therefore:

```
If constraint = ">" And x > y Then
  'code
ElseIf constraint = "<" And x < y Then
  'code
End If
```

Comment: I would just note that the performance on this would actually be worse than OP's code as there is not short circuiting in VBA. If it's a performance critical piece of code, the more verbose method may be better. Regardless, +1.

Comment: Sorry, on reflection my code isn't that clear. The operation of either < or > depends on the constraint; I'm basically searching a column of data and search for values greater than or less than a set value. So if I send ">" then I need that to take it's place in all the conditions to record it, and if I send "<" then I need that to be there instead.